# Firebase Cloud Messaging, topic with more than 1000 users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm designing the future notification system for an app, and wondering about how topic subscriptions work.
According to the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions) the following note states:

> Note: You can subscribe up to 1,000 devices in a single request. If
>   you provide an array with over 1,000 registration tokens, the request
>   will fail with a messaging/invalid-argument error.

Does that also mean that a topic can't have more than 1000 subscribers? Or would I be able to exceed that 1000 user limit if I register devices one by one?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging):

> Topic messaging supports unlimited topics and subscriptions for each app.

The [note](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions) in this page, means the array can only have 1000 tokens in one request, if you add more than 1000 then you will get an error.

Comment: This is great! Just what is was looking for, thanks :)